# Unable to access some websites outside US GCP

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform

I have a project on GCP that all machines stay on Southamerica (A,B or C). The machines on any Southamerica zone are unable to access some websites, currently I found those two websites:

- https://cnisnet.inss.gov.br/cnisinternet/faces/pages/perfil.xhtml
- https://ccm.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/login/contribuinte?tipo=F

If however I create a machine on the US Region (any zone) I can connect normally, did anyone passed trough this and were able to solve? I've tried to create a new project and use only the default network, same issue.

Thank you.

Comment: this sounds like a regional ban, so maybe you can try with [network routing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes) to go to external internet throw another point. Or use SSH [tunneling](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce) with an instance in other region. Also Compute Engine supports [protocol forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding) that can help you to achieve changing the exit point of your GCE.

Comment: Pretty odd to be a regional ban, since I can access from the same country. But I'll try to do this.

Comment: could you confirm if the workaround solved the issue?

Comment: Sorry José, I couldn't create this workaround due to my company policy. What we did found is that there's a possibility of some issue with a custom VPC subnetwork were all machines from that subnetwork are unable to access the sites, however from other subnetworks they work normally.
So for now, the work around was to put the machine on a different subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that after some day the issue "fixed itself". GCP support is still unable to understand or give a valid solution, but after some days this is working fine.

The SSH tunneling worked as expected as well, so if someone has the same issue, this can be a viable solution.